# Spark Map with RDD inside

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, graphframes

I know Spark will not allow you to use functions that generate RDDs inside of `map` or any of it's variants. Is there a work around for this? For instance, can I perform a standard looping iterations of all RDDs in a partition. (For instance is there a method to convert an RDD to a list on each node, so that each node contains a list of the entries it was carrying?)

I'm trying to do some graph work with `graphframes` in `pyspark` and it's currently not possible to do what I want.

Comment: @zero323 I don't think so since it still returns an RDD.

Comment: In that case I don't understand what you're trying to achieve :)

Comment: @zero323 I have a list of all vertices in pairs. (i.e. cartesian product) and I want to find the shortest path between all vertices. I've read that I can use Floyd-Warshall for this but in graphframes even the `find` method returns dataframes so I'm unsure how to best iterate the rdd of pairs.

Comment: How large is the graph?

Comment: @zero323 Too big for me to want to coalesce or put it on the driver.

Comment: Is it fully connected?

Comment: @zero323 I'm unsure, I believe that mathematically I can not guarantee connectivity.

Comment: I've been thinking more about identifying connected components to reduce the problem so to opposite would be more useful. Anyway... Floyd–Warshall can be implemented with message passing so you should be able to use Pregel API but I don't think that GraphFrames will be very useful for you here, unless you want to iterate vertex by vertex.